# "error: reached end of file while parsing"

Tags: java

So my AP Comp Sci lab asked me to build and erase, here's my erase code, and I've come up with the error,

**error: reached end of file while parsing**

Would love some help with it, thanks.
Obviously, there's a lot more code, if it helps, I can add it no problem.

```html
   public void erase(Graphics g, int f)
   {
     frame = f;
     if (frame == 1)
     { 
         //First
         g.drawRect(50,50,100,100);
         g.drawLine(70,70,70,100);
         g.drawLine(120,70,120,100);
         g.drawLine(70,125,100,125);
     }
     
     if (frame == 2)
     {
         //Second - Left Eye Gone
         g.drawRect(150,50,100,100);
         g.drawLine(220,70,220,100);
         g.drawLine(170,125,200,125);
     }
     
     if (frame = 3)
     {
         //Third - Right Eye Gone
         g.drawRect(250,50,100,100);
         g.drawLine(270,70,270,100);
         g.drawLine(270,125,300,125);
     }
     
     if (frame == 4)
     {
         //Fourth - Mouth Gone
         g.drawRect(350,50,100,100);
         g.drawLine(370,70,370,100);
         g.drawLine(420,70,420,100);
     }
     
     if (frame == 5)
     {
         //Fifth - Mouth and Left Eye
         g.drawRect(450,50,100,100);
         g.drawLine(520,70,520,100);          
     }
     
     if (frame == 6)
     {
         //Sixth - Mouth and Right Eye
         g.drawRect(550,50,100,100);
         g.drawLine(570,70,570,100);
     }
   }
```

Comment: This isn't javascript... Probably will get more helpful replies if you use the correct language tag.

Comment: if (frame = 3) is likely an error.  Did you mean if (frame == 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this error message when I'm missing a bracket somewhere, but it looks like those are all accounted for here.  I would check the rest of the file and make sure that you aren't missing a bracket anywhere else.

Comment: So yeah, I encountered that issue, and that was the basis of my issue. After adding one at the end of the code, it began to compile with no errors.